# LEFT JOIN With Redundant Predicate Performs Better Than a CROSS JOIN?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I'm looking at the execution plans for two of these statements and am kind of stumped on why the `LEFT JOIN` statement performs better than the `CROSS JOIN` statement:

Table Definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE [Employee] (
    [ID]                int             NOT NULL    IDENTITY(1,1),
    [FirstName]         varchar(40)     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Numbers] (
    [N] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Numbers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([N] ASC)
); --The Numbers table contains numbers 0 to 100,000.
```

Queries in Question where I join one 'day' to each Employee:

```
DECLARE @PeriodStart AS date = '2019-11-05';
DECLARE @PeriodEnd AS date = '2019-11-05';

SELECT E.FirstName, CD.ClockDate
FROM Employee E
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DATEADD(day, N.N, @PeriodStart) AS ClockDate 
                FROM Numbers N 
                WHERE N.N <= DATEDIFF(day, @PeriodStart, @PeriodEnd)
        ) CD
WHERE E.ID > 2000;

SELECT E.FirstName, CD.ClockDate
FROM Employee E
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATEADD(day, N.N, @PeriodStart) AS ClockDate 
                FROM Numbers N 
                WHERE N.N <= DATEDIFF(day, @PeriodStart, @PeriodEnd)
        ) CD ON CD.ClockDate = CD.ClockDate
WHERE E.ID > 2000;
```

The Execution Plans:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B139JjPKK

[image: CROSS JOIN and LEFT JOIN Plan]

As you can see, according to the optimizer the second (left join) query with the seemingly redundant predicate seems to cost way less than the first (cross join) query. This is also the case when the period dates span multiple days.

What's weird is if I change the LEFT JOIN's predicate to something different like `1 = 1` it'll perform like the CROSS APPLY. I also tried changing the SELECT portion of the LEFT JOIN to `SELECT N` and joined on `CD.N = CD.N` ... but that also seems to perform poorly.

According to the execution plan, the second query has an index seek that only reads 3000 rows from the Numbers table while the first query is reading 10 times as many. The second query's index seek also has this predicate (which I assume comes from the LEFT JOIN):

`dateadd(day,[Numbers].[N] as [N].[N],[@PeriodStart])=dateadd(day,[Numbers].[N] as [N].[N],[@PeriodStart])`

I would like to understand why the second query seems to perform so much better even though I wouldn't except it to? Does it have something to do with the fact I'm joining the results of the DATEADD function? Is SQL evaluating the results of DATEADD before joining?

Comment: Is CD.ClockDate ever null?

Comment: Your primary issue to me seems to be the table spool: you should optimize this by selecting only the amount of rows you need `CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(day, @PeriodStart, @PeriodEnd)) DATEADD(day, N.N, @PeriodStart) AS ClockDate FROM Numbers N ORDER BY N.N)`. Please upload the two query plans to https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan so we can see what's really going on.

Comment: @CaiusJard Indeed, `DATEADD` returns a nullable, see fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fba475d53171aec1b8cb4229b10f92e7. That is probably causing the row estimate to be lowered, as you rightly guessed

Comment: The percentages given as 'query cost (relative to the batch)' are _estimates_ rather than actuals. In your first query, it's expecting 633 thousand rows to be processed, while in the second it expects only 63 thousand. As such, it estimates the bottom one to be much less work even though it may be the same. To properly test, try `SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON;` THEN running the queries and viewing numbers of scans, reads etc to compare. Looking at the query plans, I expect them to actually be very similar amount of work.

Comment: @Charlieface Here is the plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B139JjPKK

I also ran it with your optimization and it seems to perform way better than both of my queries. Thanks!

Comment: @seanb You are correct, it appears the scans and reads are the same. With a date range that produces 131,000 rows each query, the `CROSS JOIN` had a 141ms CPU Time and a 219ms Elapsed Time, and the `LEFT JOIN` query was 121ms CPU and 735ms Elapsed. Interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason these queries get different estimates, even though the plan is almost the same and will probably take the same time, appears to be because `DATEADD(day, N.N, @PeriodStart)` is nullable, therefore `CD.ClockDate = CD.ClockDate` essentially just verifies that the result is not null. The optimizer cannot see that it will always be non-null, so takes the row-estimate down because of it.

---

But it seems to me that the primary performance problem in your query is that you are selecting the whole of your numbers table every time. Instead you should just select the amount of rows you need

```sql
SELECT E.FirstName, CD.ClockDate
FROM Employee E
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(day, @PeriodStart, @PeriodEnd) + 1)
            DATEADD(day, N.N, @PeriodStart) AS ClockDate
        FROM Numbers N
        ORDER BY N.N
    ) CD
WHERE E.ID > 2000;
```

Using this technique, you can even use `CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (outerValue)` if you want to correlate the amount of rows to the rest of the query.

For further tips on numbers tables, see [Itzik Ben-Gan's excellent series](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1)